# Adding an additional loop in the given diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, feynman

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current  bounding  box.center)]
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (x);
\vertex[above left=of x] (a);
\vertex[below left=of x] (b);
\vertex[above right=of x] (c);
\vertex[below right=of x] (d);
\diagram*{
    (x) --[fermion] (a),
    (x) --[fermion] (b),
    (x) --[fermion] (c),
    (x) --[fermion] (d),
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above code gives the following diagram:

[image]

What I want do is add a loop in the above diagrams as follows:

[image]

but one constraint is that the overall size of the diagram does not change after adding this loop.

> How can I do this?

> In particular, how can I add more nodes in the midpoint of the preexisting nodes?